# CreateUploadSession returning 403

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, onedrive

Trying to make a post request to

```
POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online

I expected a 200 response with an upload url, but got a 403, despite having all relevant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint seems to require a `PUT` request instead of `POST` despite all other answered posts and the documentation indicating otherwise

Comment: So you started seeing `createUploadSession` work as expected when you used `PUT`? That's definitely unexpected..